# odoo11 log generation when i change data in a field using CSV Import

Tags: python, odoo-11

In Odoo11, When a field is changed by any user, It generates a log. for that I use **track_visibility** in field.

```
`audit_user = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='Audit User', track_visibility='onchange')
 audit_date = fields.Datetime(string="Audit Date", track_visibility='onchange')
 is_audited = fields.Boolean(string='Is Audited', track_visibility='onchange')`
```

[image]

That's The log is generated after any user change the data in these fields.

I can also update data of these fields using CSV Import of Odoo.

*No log is generating when i changed field using CSV Import.*

I want to generate a log when I change field data using CSV Import Option of Odoo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by Method Overriding of Import function, providing you an example of custom log note generation code snippets

```
    self.env['mail.message'].create({
        'body': <your message>,
        'message_type': 'comment',
        'subtype_id': self.env.ref('mail.mt_note').id,
        'model': <your model name>,
        'res_id': <model's object id where you want to post>
    })
```